# Delete records which is not used in another table

Tags: mysql

I have to delete many records from my one table from mysql. But some of records has foreign key relations with other records. So, When I fire delete command, Its shows me error regarding foreign key, and rollback whole delete transaction (which is natural). In this case I have to filter those records which is used (referenced) in other tables, and then delete. Is there any why to delete records without doing filter? means If I fire delete command, delete those records which is not used (referenced), and skip which is used in another table, without showing error or rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` to check for relations and delete all records having no relations

```
delete t1
from tableToDeleteFrom t1
left join referenceTable t2 on t1.foreignKeyColumn = t2.keyColumn
where t2.keyColumn is null
and <your delete conditions>
```

If you want a quick and dirty solution you can use the `ignore` keyword to ignore errors during execution:

> The IGNORE keyword causes MySQL to ignore errors during the process of deleting rows. (Errors encountered during the parsing stage are processed in the usual manner.) Errors that are ignored due to the use of IGNORE are returned as warnings.

```
delete ignore from tableToDeleteFrom
where <your delete conditions>
```

Comment: thanks @juergen-d, my problem is, my table has so many records and linked with atleaste 10-12 tables (that also huge table), so This take more time to execute, and impacting bad performance on my live database. Is there any other solution?